# Kotlin: Find the first line of a file that matches a regex, and return captured values

Tags: kotlin

i want get text from a file by using regEx and want save the file with a new name (using the results of the regEx-Find).

My Problem is that **i cant get/return the correct genearated (in this example `xyz maur`) out of the function** `readFileLineByLineUsingForEachLine(fileName: String)` the new newFileName which was generated (sucessfully as expected) in the function.

Line 1 of Source:

`start {"Name":"xyz","Civ":"maur","Team":0}`

My Prototype:

```
fun main() {
    val f = "./commands.txt";
    var newFileName = readFileLineByLineUsingForEachLine(f)
    print(newFileName.)
    val source = Paths.get(f)
    val target = Paths.get("/home/x/snap/0ad/199/.local/share/0ad/replays/0.0.24/2021-03-14_0016/" + newFileName)
//    try {
//        val move = Files.move(
//            source,
//            target
//        )
//    } catch (e: IOException) {
//        e.printStackTrace()
//    }
};

fun readFileLineByLineUsingForEachLine(fileName: String) // https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/read-file
        = File(fileName).forEachLine lit@{
    // "Name":"Cleisthenes"
    val regexString = """
    "Name":(?<Name>"\w+").*?"Civ":(?<Civ>"\w+").*?"Team":0
            """.trim()
    var regex = Regex(regexString)
    var matched = regex.find(it)?.groupValues
    val Name = matched?.get(1)
    val Civ = matched?.get(2)
    if (Name != null)
        println(Name)
    if (Civ != null)
        println(Civ)
    val newFileName = "$Name $Civ"
    return@lit
}
```

Comment: Could you include your source file and desired output? Also, if the file is XML, then using an XML parser would be a better idea than trying to use regular expressions. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @AdamMillerchip Line 1 of Source:
`start {"Name":"xyz","Civ":"maur","Team":0}`
as i said. parsing the source is not my problem

Comment: What's with the attitude problem? "as I said" - you didn't say that, you edited it in two minutes before your comment. The sample input will make it easier for people to understand what you are trying to do, so I think it was worth adding.

Comment: Do you want `readFileLineByLineUsingForEachLine` to return the file name `xyz maur`?

Comment: 'i cant get out of the function'. I am a native German speaker. I try my best to speak in english. do I have to explain something else? I will need the result later for a new file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you want to stop processing as soon as you find a match, I don't think `forEachLine` is the best choice. Instead you can use [`useLines`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/use-lines.html), and combine it with [`first`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/first.html) to stop processing once you get a match:

```
val regex = Regex(""""Name":(?<Name>"\w+").*?"Civ":(?<Civ>"\w+").*?"Team":0""")

fun readFileLineByLineUsingForEachLine(fileName: String) =
    File(fileName).useLines { lines ->
        val (name, civ) = lines
            .map { regex.find(it) }
            .filterNotNull()
            .first()
            .destructured

        "$name $civ"
    }
```

For the example you provided, this returns the string `"xyz" "maur"`.

Comment: difficult to reuse your example. i got the error `Unresolved reference: regex`. I will find a solution with it. Thank you

Comment: Ah, sorry I forgot to include the regex definition . Fixed now. I defined it outside the function to avoid re-creating it for every line of the file.

Comment: yours looks a bit more pretty i think. did you tested it?

Comment: Yes I tested it. I still think you should consider using a JSON parsing library if this is something you are going to be maintaining for longer that 5 minutes.

Comment: the complete File looks like correct JSON for me: https://i.imgur.com/aC3NMH2.png , https://wildfiregames.com/forum/topic/35314-ratings-disputes-and-offence-reporting/?do=findComment&comment=343612

Comment: In that file, the input you're looking for is on the first line. So it seems like looping through all the lines is not needed - but it was impossible to tell that from your code sample. This is why providing the input when you ask the question is important.

Answer (score 0):

that's just a very little modification of the correct, helpful answer from Adam here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66654710/2891692

```
fun readFileLineByLineUsingForEachLine2(fileName: String) =
    File(fileName).useLines { lines ->
        val (name, civ) = lines
            .map {
                val regexString = """
"Name":(?<Name>"\w+").*?"Civ":(?<Civ>"\w+").*?"Team":0
            """.trim()
                var regex = Regex(regexString)
                regex.find(it)
            }
            .filterNotNull()
            .first()
            .destructured
        "$name $civ"
    }
```